# Passing JSON in content body to an end point using PostAsync

Tags: c#, json, webforms

I'm trying to post Json data in the content body to an endpoint through a button click event using PostAsync in my sending application. I've also tried PostAsJsonAsync but I get the same results. Is the issue with the way I'm sending the JSON or receiving?
Here's my button click event:

```
protected async void btnSendJsonPage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string myJson = "{\"transaction_number\": \"12345\",\"confirmation_number\":\"abcde\",\"amount\":\"1900\"}";
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var response = await client.PostAsync(
            "http://ReceivingApplication/Postback.aspx",
             new StringContent(myJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
    }
}
```

And here's the end point method that is getting called from the page load of my receiving application:

```
public async void GetJson(string url)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
                    {
                        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode & response.Content != null)
                        {
                            using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                            {
                                string contentBody = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                                
                                var obj = JObject.Parse(contentBody.ToString());
                                var transactionNumber = (string)obj["transaction_number"];
                                var confirmationNumber = (string)obj["confirmation_number"];
                                var amount = (string)obj["amount"];
                            }                                   
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

The Json is not being passed in the `contentBody`. As you can see, there is no Json here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head><title>

</title></head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="./SendJson.aspx" id="form1">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="so6PdTwsll6p8yPpP9Rs//1ONb6VQ/N3rq2zbBgrURrMLdSC4kY4EE9V6w0a5ZPGzO0BOsCErjIgNkpsCmeNJydwn7JoFrqHbI+lyPbjWpU=" />

<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="42E0F1BD" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="KQQzzLdJzQh7CB9kQ69WA6nFKR9RwPd3xbw4mKAPOIR6D6PG/WbDnQYga2kHZ0uC5YPzObwyS000zJtInEH2ruUc3dCjTlGY9kQXAePdL6Je4KNNoshKin/O+f1w8ztm" />
        <div>
            
    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSendJson" value="Send Json in Body" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSendJson" class="btn btn-primary" />

        </div>
    </form>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the exception I get as there's no Json in the body:

```
Unexpected character encountered while parsing value
```

Comment: Json string you are using contains single quotes... should be double quote for it to work

Comment: @Jawad - I replaced the single quotes with double quotes but that didn't seem to help.

Comment: Can you update your post with the substituted string declaration

Comment: @Jawad - I have updated the post. Thanks.

Comment: Be sure to read [You're Using HttpClient Wrong](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2019/09/using-http.aspx#:~:text=You%27re%20Using%20HttpClient%20Wrong%20There%27s%20a%20very%20good,call%20the%20object%27s%20Dispose%20method%20before%20discarding%20it%29.) since there's a high likelihood you are.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

```
public async void GetJson(string url)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
                    {
                        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode & response.Content != null)
                        {
                            using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                            {
                                string contentBody = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                               
                                var obj = JObject.Parse(contentBody);
                                var json_obj=obj["json"];
                                var transactionNumber = (string)json_obj["transaction_number"];
                                var confirmationNumber = (string)json_obj["confirmation_number"];
                                var amount = (string)json_obj["amount"];
                            }                                   
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

If this doesn't work then use debugging to check the value of the contentBody string variable. If it is empty then you can focus on whether there is an issue with sending or receiving the JSON.